# PlotLegends makes Manipulate[] ing graphs slow to a crawl

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I have a short program set up to display three plots of the same function with different parameters using Manipulate.  I'd like to label each function with the value of the parameter.  My starting point was to just get a legend to show up at all.  Adding a PlotLegend to the plot causes Mathematica to become unusably slow.

My code is:

```
Needs["PlotLegends`"]
Manipulate[

 UemaxOverUe = ((VA/Vphs)^2 (2 p - 1) + 1 - Ves0/Vphs - 2)/((VA/Vphs)^2 - (1 - Ves0/Vphs));

 UemaxOverUe2 = ((VA/Vphs)^2 (2 p - 1) + 1 - Ves02/Vphs - 2)/((VA/Vphs)^2 - (1 - Ves02/Vphs));

 UemaxOverUe3 = ((VA/Vphs)^2 (2 p - 1) + 1 - Ves03/Vphs - 2)/((VA/Vphs)^2 - (1 - Ves03/Vphs));

 ListPlot[{
  Table[{Vphs/VA, 1/UemaxOverUe}, {Vphs, .001 VA, VA, .01 VA}], 
  Table[{Vphs/VA, 1/UemaxOverUe2}, {Vphs, .001 VA, VA, .01 VA}], 
  Table[{Vphs/VA, 1/UemaxOverUe3}, {Vphs, .001 VA, VA, .01 VA}]}, 
  AxesLabel -> {"Vphs/VA", "Ne/NeMax"}, Joined -> True(*,
  PlotLegend->{"Blah","Blarg","Word"}*)],

 {{p, 1}, 0, 5},
 {{Ves0, -2 VA}, -10 VA, 10 VA, .1 VA},
 {{Ves02, -2 VA}, -10 VA, 10 VA, .1 VA},
 {{Ves03, -2 VA}, -10 VA, 10 VA, .1 VA}
]
```

Uncommenting the `PlotLegend` should recreate the problem.

My questions are: 
 Why does this happen?
 What is a good solution, or workaround?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem seems to be that PlotLegend is just slow. It hasn't got anything to do with `Manipulate`. On my PC The `ListPlot` takes 0.013 s without a legend and 0.43 second if a legend is added.

As a workaround you could use

```
ControlActive[{}, PlotLegend -> {"Blah", "Blarg", "Word"}]]
```

instead of just the `PlotLegend` to show the legend only when you're not moving the sliders.

Comment: Yes, `PlotLegend` is ridiculously slow given what it is meant to be doing. So are the bar chart functions relative to line plot functions. That's why I proposed `Epilog` as an alternative.

Comment: Thanks, Sjoerd.  

That is ridiculously slow for adding a plot legend!

Answer (score 4):

An alternative to Sjoerd's answer might be to reconstruct the legend as an `Epilog`, given that you know you have three series to plot.