# How is this dynamic plot possible with mathematica?

Tags: graphics, wolfram-mathematica

Here is a BBC dynamic [graphics](http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/business-15748696). I am thinking it might be possible to reproduce the graphics in Mathematica.

[image]

In the process of answering we will see some charming graphics tricks available in MMA. That is the only reason to ask the question out here.

**Update:**

I just checked that BBC is using simple JavaScript to do it. They have manually made the static pictures and not even using Flash based event handling. So all the pictures are static entities and once we click on one country it generates a unique image. For other countries it shows other images. The separate images for each cases can be generated via PowerPoint, Visio or even Photoshop. One can check this just by disabling the JavaScript in your browser and by reloading the page.

I understand that those single pictures can be made from MMA. Some answers shows the right direction how one can do it. So I am accepting the best answer that has come so far.

Comment: Most elements can be found easily within Mathematica. You can have `Arrow`s, for instance based on `BezierCurve`s or `BSplineCurve`s. The clickable names can be implemented as a `Button` with `Appearance->"Frameless"`. The rest is just work. Perhaps the variable thickness of the arrows in the graphics might be hard to reproduce. Might be necessary to refrain from using `Arrow` and built them from more basic drawing primitives. What did you try yourself before asking this question?

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries I did not try so far. Just now read the news in BBC and thought it will be a good problem for a MMA practice lesson. I will try to do it but wanted others to have a look too. Specially those gtting bored on a foggy Saturday morning.

Comment: I think that while this takes a lot of work, it's not a too difficult task.  You'll need to wrap graphics objects in `EventHandler`, make clicks modify some variables, and put the whole `Graphics` in `Dynamic` so it updates when those vars change.  `HighlightGraph` is good for a simplified solution.  Make a directed graph `g` then do `SetterBar[Dynamic[colour], {Red, Green, Blue}]`, `Dynamic@
  HighlightGraph[g, {Style[1 \[DirectedEdge] 2, colour]}]`

Comment: @Plato There are too many boring details there, but I don't see any really difficult task. If you don't know how to draw a specific object in your graph we may help, but a lot of time is needed to reproduce all the small details.

Comment: I agree with belisarius and szabolcs here. There is way too many details to reproduce and not really a good use of the community's time. I'm voting to close as "too localized"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just another starter:

```
a = Point[{0, 0}];
b = .75 Tuples[{1, -1}, 2][[{3, 1, 2, 4}]];
PieChart[
 {
  Button[1, (a = {Thickness[.05], Arrowheads[.1], 
      Arrow[BSplineCurve@{b[[1]], {0, 0}, #}] & /@ b})],
  Button[1, (a = {Thickness[.05], Arrowheads[.1], 
      Arrow[BSplineCurve@{b[[2]], {0, 0}, #}] & /@ b})],
  Button[1, (a = {Thickness[.05], Arrowheads[.1], 
      Arrow[BSplineCurve@{b[[3]], {0, 0}, #}] & /@ b})],
  Button[1, (a = {Thickness[.05], Arrowheads[.1], 
      Arrow[BSplineCurve@{b[[4]], {0, 0}, #}] & /@ b})],
  }
 ,
 SectorOrigin -> {Automatic, 1},
 Epilog -> Dynamic@a]
```

[image]

**Edit** More compact:

```
a = Point[{0, 0}];
b = .75 Tuples[{1, -1}, 2][[{3, 1, 2, 4}]];
PieChart[
 ReleaseHold[Replace[Table[
    List[1, 
     ReplaceAll[
      Hold[a = {Thickness[.05], Arrowheads[.1], 
         Arrow[BSplineCurve@{k, {0, 0}, #}] & /@ b}], k -> i]],
    {i, b}], List -> Button, {2}, Heads -> True]]
 ,
 SectorOrigin -> {Automatic, 1},
 Epilog -> Dynamic@a]
```

Comment: (I have wanted to draw diagrams like this for a while...) The thing is, OP fails to really mention that the widths of the curved arrows are supposed to be in proportion to the flows they represent. More elaborate diagrams of this type have curved arrows going 'both ways'---showing the magnitude of flows in and out from all possible sources. IMO, there is no silver-bullet in Mathematica... It would be MUCH easier to attempt if one could, say, specify a Line[] that would change widths as a function of In/out magnitudes, which likely differ on both ends of more complex examples.

Comment: @tele I realized the variable arrow width thing, but also a lot of other smaller and bigger details in the OP's graph. It may demand a lot of time to address them all, and besides that, it is quite boring. But ... I think you have a nice question there to post here... something like: "How to make an arrow with parametrized width along its arc?"

Comment: I have a lot of questions I'd like to ask, but find it very tedious to make sure to properly explain exactly what it is I'm trying to do. Design and integration issues are always on my mind as well, which is a lot to cram into a single question, and seems to push the limit of what SO is intended for. I wish there were an organized way (for MMA users) to coordinate solving some of these types of 'big' problems and to work on open source stuff together. IMO, WRI would really need to be involved somehow too. I get frustrated by the walled off knowledge, inaccessible to us on the outside.

Comment: It might be that my initial assumption that the arrows change in width along their course is mistaken. It might be that the partial overlap between some of them cause them to have this appearance.

Answer (score 4):

Some more basic footwork for this:

```
g[\[Alpha]_, \[Beta]_, color_] := Module[{t},
 t = Graphics[{{Thickness[.03], Arrowheads[{.15}], color,
  Arrow[
   BezierCurve[{{Cos[\[Alpha]], Sin[\[Alpha]]}, {0, 
      0}, {Cos[\[Beta]], Sin[\[Beta]]}}]]}},
PlotRange -> 1.5, ImageSize -> 512, Background -> None];
ImageCompose[Blur[t, 15], t]
]

one = Fold[ImageCompose, 
 g[0, \[Pi]/3, Blue], {g[0, \[Pi]/2, Blue], g[0, \[Pi], Blue], 
 g[0, 4 \[Pi]/3, Blue]}]

two = Fold[ImageCompose, 
 g[\[Pi]/3, 0, Yellow], {g[\[Pi]/3, \[Pi]/2, Yellow], 
 g[\[Pi]/3, \[Pi], Yellow], g[\[Pi]/3, 4 \[Pi]/3, Yellow]}]

DynamicModule[{pick = 1},
 ClickPane[
  Dynamic@If[pick == 1, one, two],
  Function[{point}, If[First[point] < 256, pick = 1, pick = 2]]]
 ]
```

[image]

Comment: Nice shadows! Congrats with your first 1000 pts BTW

Comment: Thanks. I'm wondering if all primitives shouldn't have more rendering directives like this ( {AbsoluteShadow[n], Arrow[pts] }

Comment: This is also a much nicer shadow than the one `PlotLegends` currently has. But perhaps better not add it as it is already slow as it is now (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8189742/plotlegends-makes-manipulate-ing-graphs-slow-to-a-crawl/8189802#8189802).

Answer (score 3):

This is not a full answer, but it's too long for a comment.  I encourage everyone to "steal" from it, and complete it :-)

```
g = RandomGraph[{5, 12}, DirectedEdges -> True];

SetterBar[Dynamic[v], VertexList[g]]

Dynamic@HighlightGraph[
  g, {Style[Cases[EdgeList[g], v \[DirectedEdge] _], 
    Directive[Thick, Black]], Style[v, Red]}, 
  GraphLayout -> "CircularEmbedding", EdgeStyle -> Lighter@Gray, 
  VertexLabels -> "Name"]
```

[image]

The next step is using `VertexShapeFunction` with objects wrapped in `EventHandler` to replace the `SetterBar`.

Comment: I don't like the wobbliness of the arrows in the Graph graphics

Comment: @Sjoerd That can be customized too, and `GraphPlot` has a different default.  Anyway, this was just a starting point, not intended as something even close to a final solution.  Maybe that one won't even use graphs.  I posted only to make it easier for others to get started (if anyone wishes to use this).